# Strange Behavior With IIS and Http Methods

Tags: jquery, ajax, backend, put, iis-8

I have some strange behavior going on with IIS and some jquery ajax calls using a PUT type. I have two websites; website A and website B; both have the same code; in fact I copied the files from A to B for testing purposes. In my script I have PUT ajax type. On site A the PUT fails and returns a status code of 500 (Internal Server error) but on site B the PUT works fine and my data on the API side is updated. Oh! the PUT works fine in my development environment just fine (of course). Now, here's the real kicker, I replace the PUT Http type with POST on site A then the process works. My goal is to try to understand what is going on and where the error is coming from. If anyone has any suggestions or things to try that would be great. Below is the ajax call from my script.

```
let dataView = new PersonDeductionModel(self);
let jsonView = { deductionApplicationJson: ko.toJSON(dataView) };
self.isLoaded(false);
$.ajax({
  url: modifyDeductionInformationURL,
  data: JSON.stringify(jsonView),
  type: "PUT",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: jsonContentType,
})
  .done(function (jsonObject, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    self.isUpdating(false);
    if (jsonObject.statusCode === 400) {
      window.location =
        "DeductionErrorOccurred?statuscode=" + jsonObject.statusCode;
    } else {
      window.location = "ThankYou?statuscode=" + jsonObject.statusCode;
    }
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    self.isUpdating(false);
    console.log(jqXHR.statuscode);
  })
  .always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    self.isLoaded(true);
  });
```

Comment: Check the server error logs. Hard to help debug the client code without the specific debugging details/errors. Also inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see that everything (headers, body,, url) etc are as expected

Comment: Server logs aren't really telling me anything. I can see the 500 error in the log but there's no error message.

Comment: I haven't worked with IIS in years but that sounds very strange that no message exists

Comment: You may also want to tag this with applicable back end stack tags